# Bias voltage higher than input voltage

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, dc-dc-converter, ldo

Can someone explain why the voltage on the Bias pin should be higher than the input voltage n this [LDO](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic47050.pdf)?

What is the reason behind it?

Why is the bias voltage on different pin? For what purpose? How can it have overlapping voltage ranges with the input voltage?

Comment: I don't 100% understand your question. The datasheet shows that the bias voltage and the input voltage have an overlapping range. But it does not actually say that the bias voltage should be higher than the input voltage.

Comment: As far as I can see, it would work fine with bias = 2.5 V and input = 3.6 V, for example. Are you wondering why they are separate at all in the first place? Don't answer in the comment section. Update your question by editing it to make it more clear.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIC47050 uses the bias voltage to power the amplifiers and control circuitry in the regulator.

The MIC47050 is intended for low voltage regulation.  It uses a slightly higher voltage for the control circuits to regulate the lower voltages.

- "Bias" is the power supply for the regulator.
- "In" is the source that provides the power to the regulated output.

I expect the reason it is done this way is to get better performance.

Circuit design gets more difficult the lower the source voltage.  It gets harder to get good performance.

With the split design of the MIC47050, the designer can use higher voltage for the critical parts of the regulator.  The low voltage is only handled by the pass transistor.

This drawing from the datasheet show how it works:

[image]

The red line is where current flows from the "IN" power source to the regulated "OUT."  Pretty much everything else in the IC is powered from the "Bias"

Comment: To add to this -- note dropout is specified in two ways: Vbias to Vout (which is large!), and Vin to Vout (which is minuscule).  As long as you're meeting both dropout figures, you'll get expected performance. And yeah, NMOS is good for stability, in contrast to PNP and PMOS types which are often plagued by poor transient response, PSRR, stability (requires specific Cout, ESR), and current consumption (esp. PNP in dropout).

Comment: The key takeaway is that this regulator has an NMOS pass transistor. Its gate voltage needs to be at least one Vgs theshold above Vin. So its drive circuit needs to also have a corresponding higher voltage. In this case, it's provided by a bias pin; it could in theory be provided by an on-chip boost converter as is done for some LDOs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make a linear voltage regulator:

[image]

On the left, we have a N pass device, used as follower, ie common collector if it's a BJT, or common drain if it's a FET. This configuration has one large drawback: the error amp must drive the base/gate to Vout plus the threshold voltage of the pass device. This means it must output a voltage that is high enough, which requires enough power supply voltage. That's why these regulators are usually not low-dropout. Examples of this configuration would be LM317, 7805, etc.

On the right, a P-channel FET or PNP is used as pass device, in common emitter/common source configuration. This removes the dropout voltage restriction, as the error amp no longer needs to drive the gate/base above the output voltage. Instead, it has to be driven below the input voltage, which allows low dropout.

However, the LDO configuration has several drawbacks.

One drawback occurs at low input voltages, like 1.5V and below. In this case, the same problem occurs as in the previous topology, but turned upside down: since the error amp can't output a negative voltage, the PMOS must have very low threshold voltage to be able to be fully turned on by the error amp. This means it's going to be a big slow MOSFET with a lot of capacitance. In addition, the error amp doesn't have much voltage to work with. It's a lot easier to make a good performance opamp with 3V supply than 1.2V.

Your LDO simply offers a separate power pin for the error amp, that is supposed to be used with a higher supply voltage. This allows using a N pass device (the topology on the left) without the high dropout voltage drawback. Error amp performance is improved due to the higher available supply voltage too.

Generally, for the same current, RdsON and threshold voltage, a N channel MOSFET will have higher performance than a P channel. The N channel will be smaller, faster, and cheaper. So this topology also allows a better pass device.

If you look at your LDO's datasheet, you'll notice the PSRR from the power input is pretty good, but the PSRR from the error amp's power pin is a lot worse. However, the error amp draws little power, so its power supply can be filtered with a simple RC filter. So, this topology offers a way to improve PSRR.

In addition, the N pass device behaves as a follower, whereas the P pass device behaves as a controlled current source. This means the N device offers a zero, while the P device adds a dominant pole together with the output cap. I'll spare you the details, but with a N pass device, the LDO is less dependent on output capacitor characteristics, and it is possible to implement a faster control loop, which results in faster/better transient response and lower output impedance.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem a bit odd.

From the examples in the datasheet it looks like their intention is to use this regulator to generate very low relatively low noise voltages using a DC-DC converter as an input. DC-DC converters tend to have high ripple voltages. Following a DC-DC with a linear regulator can produce cleaner power sometimes.

For example if you had a lithium ion battery followed by a 1.8 V DC-DC converter, you could use the battery voltage for bias, and use the 1.8 V output of the DC-DC for Vin. From this you could produce a low-ripple 1.2 V supply for a low-voltage processor of some sort.

I guess the higher bias voltage makes the regulator a bit easier to design. This regulator is capable of unusually low output voltages, and I think it would be very difficult to design an LDO that can produce 1 V output from 1.5 V input, for example. But this one can do that, as long as bias is above 2.3 V.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always have to be higher than the input, as far as I can see.

In their "typical application," they put a buck converter on the 3.3V supply to get 1.8V, which they use to drive the LDO.  This isn't strictly necessary on the face of it, but it causes the LDO to dissipate less than 1/3 the power it would have if Vin was connected directly to 3.3V.  This reduces the stress on the LDO and on power requirements overall.

However, while the LDO can work down to 1V Vin, it needs bias of at least 2.3V to properly operate the op amps and other analog circuitry.  If the supply is between 2.3V and 3.6V, Vin and bias can both be driven together.